# Android Broadcast Receiver and separating data

Tags: android, performance, optimization, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I would like to know now I'm using Broadcast receiver with intent service in my application.It's work well now.
1) I don't want to carry data from broadcast receiver. I want to carry data separately. 
is there any advice for me to improve broadcast receiver in android.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question, it is very hard to understand

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: @TimCastelijns In my code,
1) MainActivity Call IntentService which get the data from database and broadcast this
data to activity.
And then broadcast receiver in MainActivity received this data and display this data.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Actually my app is work well now.I want to optimize my code,I don't want to put data to broadcast.

Comment: Try to use interface and get data directly from IntentService.

Comment: @NitinPatel thank you.It is the way what I am not thinking.I'll try with it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to move away from using `BroadcastReceiver` to get the callback, but you don't say why. Here are some possible alternatives:

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` (if you aren't already). This makes sure that your data is not broadcast out of your app (security and overhead issues). This is also somewhat lighter weight (better performance) than using a normal `sendBroadcast()` call.

You can switch from an `IntentService` to a bound `Service`. You can define a synchronous call using AIDL from your `Activity` to your `Service`. Your `Activity` will then bind to the `Service` and call a method on the `Service` which will return the data as the result of the method call. No need for `BroadcastReceiver` in this case.

You can cheat and use a `public static` variable that holds a reference to your `Activity` (set the reference to `this` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`). When the `Service` wants to send the data to the `Activity`, it can just use the reference to your `Activity` and call any method on it to pass the data back. No need for `BroadcastReceiver` in this case. This is a HACK. If you use this, make sure that you check the `public static` variable to ensure it is not `null` before you use it. Also, this will cause a memory leak because the garbage collector will be unable to reclaim the instance of your `Activity` when your `Activity` finishes, but that is probably no big deal since Android will eventually kill off the OS process hosting your application anyway. I wouldn't worry about it.